# i need to know how to call curl with api key parameter with given command

Tags: php, curl

i have curl command provided by some developer, i need to know how to call it in php.

Command is :

```
curl -H "x-api-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"https://api.civicengine.com/office-
holders?address=1060+W+Addison+Chicago+IL"
```

i have written this

```
$data['api-key']='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
/*$data['host']='https://api.civicengine.com';*/

$url='https://api.civicengine.com/office-holders?address=1060+W+Addison+Chicago+IL';
$ch = curl_init();

// set basic auth
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

// set header accept
$headers = array('Accept:application/json', 'Accept-Language:en_US',"Authorization: Bearear xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// set mode to POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// add post fields (1)

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Execute
print_r($result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)));die;
```

i expect result but its giving

> stdClass Object ( [message] => Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=FLUdjGvxuJ9liutivB0Ll5LW2t2xmv31lvK2guQi )

Comment: `-H` means header, so you need to add this to the request headers you are sending.

Comment: (FYI, for simple cases https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ can often do most of the work for you.)

Comment: yes, it converts curl command to PHP code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the `x-api-key` header to your php curl_ code. also your php code is altering the `Accept` `Accept-Language`, and `Authorization` header, your curl invocation proves that's not needed, and they may be incorrect to boot (idk), get rid of them while debugging (and once everything is working, you may add them back and check that they don't break anything..)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method to send api_key in header of API REQUEST

```
// Collection object
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    
 $headers = array(
         "APIKEY: PUT_HERE_API_KEY",
         "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
         "Accept: text/xml"
     );
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlreq);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // execute
    $result;
   //show response
    curl_close($ch);
```